# Replace Flink Sink with Async + Discarding sink to alleviate backpressure

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a project that sends data to a Sink which sometimes takes too long to respond, causing backpressure in all the previous steps.
I was wondering if replacing the Sink with a Async function + Discarding Sink will help solve this backpressure problem.
Is there any better alternative approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you might do better to implement a custom sink based on [FLIP-171: Async Sink](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/x/P5HOCg). This will be included in Flink 1.15, see [[FLINK-24041] Generic AsyncSinkBase](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-24041).